# Armor Stands Turn Black When They're In A Solid Block [1.12]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

While I was making lucky blocks I was wondering why the skulls of the armorstands turn black if their feet are into a solid block[image]

As you can see the left one turned black.
[image]

Here you can see how the armorstands are positioned. I tried everything from PersistenceRequired tags until small armorstands but I really don't find any way to avoid that dark effect. Also when I use small armor stands the skull gets smaller to so thats not a solution.

Here you can see clearly how it works and when they turn darker.[image]
and the reason is:[image]

Comment: Here's a bug report about this: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-107529

Comment: A potential solution is to use a resource pack to modify the model of the armor stand so the head is in the same block as the feet of the armor stand, instead of one block higher. Doing this will allow you to put your armor stand in the glass instead of one block lower.

Answer (score 3):

You might have noticed that entities are darker in darker areas. You can see that very clear on the arm of your player in first person mode, if you compare it in bright daylight and inside a cave. This darkness is to simulate the absence of light.
The darkness of entities is determined by the light level of the block in which the feet are situated.

Now for your armourstand: The feet are obviously in a very dark spot, because the armourstand turns black. This is because opaque blocks don't transfer any light. The light inside the block is therefore 0. The armourstand reads this value in the block and will adapt its darkness accordingly.

Comment: yes, I see but is there any way to avoid it? Like a tag or something or an other way to get skulls into blocks

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to make an armourstand ignore lightlevels unfortunately. The armourstand is also the only entity which can truly be invisible forever, so I wouldn't know an alternative unfortunately.

Comment: that's too bad ):

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid having the blasted dark spot, just make a repeating command block that is always active with this command inside (you can also use this in 1.13):`/execute @e[type=armor_stand] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:air 0 replace`

Comment: yes but then the ground will be removed and when you break the lucky block the item will fall in/trough. I'm really looking for something that avoids the coloring.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a bit late try doing this: `/summon armor_stand ~ ~-0.5 ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,Small:1b,Marker:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"yellow_concrete",Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],Pose:{Head:[180f,0f,0f]}}`

I tilted the head down so the armor stand can fit into the block and instead of using a yellow head you could use something like yellow concrete. (The command was made for 1.13)